# Android: custom ListView doesn't get populated immediately

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, adapter

I would like to create a custom ListView populated by a custom ArrayAdapter. The code works fine, but the ListView is not showing data immediately. In order to have the data shown I need to click on a random EditText of the same page, close the Keyboard and magically the ListView shows data.
I don't know if it this can have an impact but the adapter is used in a fragment,which retrieve the data from Firebase during the OnCreate method.
Below my code, I removed everything not necessary for this topic and simplified the array.

This is my Class of elements inside the array:

```
public class ListItem {

private String Description;
private String Price;

public ListItem (String Description, String Price) {
    this.Description = Description;
    this.Price = Price;
}

public String getDescription() { return Description; }

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}

}
```

The adapter is the following:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

private Context mContext;
private Integer mResource;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_description_item;
    TextView txt_price_item;
}

public CustomListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<ListItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    String Description = getItem(position).getDescription();
    String Price = getItem(position).getPrice();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.txt_description_item = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description_item);
    viewHolder.txt_price_item = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price_item);

    viewHolder.txt_description_item.setText(Description);
    viewHolder.txt_price_item.setText(Price);

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Finally this is the Fragment code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView view_list_items;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference refDatabase;
private static final String USER = "user";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myprofile, container, false);
    view_list_items = v.findViewById(R.id.list_items);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    refDatabase = database.getReference(USER);

    refDatabase.child("items").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final ArrayList<ListItem> arr_items = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("itemlist1").getChildren()) {
                final String description = ds.getKey();
                final String price = ds.getValue(String.class);

                ListItem listItem = new ListItem(description,price);
                arr_items.add(listItem);
            }

            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.layout_myItemList, arr_items);               
            view_list_items.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

**EDIT**:
I solved the issue by setting the adapter inside the 'for' cycle. Maybe it's not the most elegant solution but it works fine

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("itemlist1").getChildren()) {
                final String description = ds.getKey();
                final String price = ds.getValue(String.class);

                ListItem listItem = new ListItem(description,price);
                arr_items.add(listItem);

                CustomListAdapter adapter = new 
                CustomListAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.layout_myItemList, arr_items);               
                view_list_items.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Comment: Who in 2020 still uses ListView? I highly recommend you to switch to RecyclerView first and then see if your question still applies. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The firebase database is asynchronous i.e, the compiler doesn't wait for the code inside onDataChange() or onCancelled() to return a value. It would return all the values apart from those inside those 2 methods immediately, while for those 2 methods it would return the value when the value is available from the database. Below code might help you in better understanding

```
 refDatabase.child("items").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println("Inside onDataChange method");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
System.out.println ("Outside onDataChange method");
```

The output will be like:

```
Outside onDataChange method
Inside onDataChange method
```

Notice that comes `Outside onDataChange method` first. This is the reason why your listView doesn't show data immediately.
What you can do to keep the user engaged is, add a spinner in your view which will be visible till the data is fetched from the database. To do this, try this code.

```
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        refDatabase = database.getReference(USER);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        refDatabase.child("items").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Your code goes here
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //Error code goes here
            }
        });
```